# How to Use Array (AS) with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This script was already able to run using MySQL legacy. But I changed to the PDO on the basis of improving the security of SQL Injection

But it seems this is not as easy as turning the palm of the hand. The original code like this:

```
<?php
$dn1 = mysql_query('select c.id, c.name, c.description, c.position, (select count(t.id) from topics AS t where t.kategori=c.id and t.id2=1) AS topics, (select count(t2.id) from topics AS t2 where t2.kategori=c.id and t2.id2!=1) AS replies from categories AS c group by c.id order by c.position asc');
$nb_cats = mysql_num_rows($dn1);
while($dnn1 = mysql_fetch_array($dn1))
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td class='forum_cat'><a href="daftar.php?kategori=<?php echo $dnn1['id']; ?>" class='title'><?php echo htmlentities($dnn1['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a>
        <div class='description'><?php echo $dnn1['description']; ?></div></td>
        <td><?php echo $dnn1['topics']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dnn1['replies']; ?></td>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username']==$admin)
{
?>
        <td><a href="delete_category.php?id=<?php echo $dnn1['id']; ?>"><img src='<?php echo $design2; ?>/images/delete.png' alt='Delete' /></a>
        <?php if($dnn1['position']>1){ ?><a href="move_category.php?action=up&id=<?php echo $dnn1['id']; ?>"><img src='<?php echo $design2; ?>/images/up.png' alt='Move Up' /></a><?php } ?>
        <?php if($dnn1['position']<$nb_cats){ ?><a href="move_category.php?action=down&id=<?php echo $dnn1['id']; ?>"><img src='<?php echo $design2; ?>/images/down.png' alt='Move Down' /></a><?php } ?>
        <a href="edit_category.php?id=<?php echo $dnn1['id']; ?>"><img src='<?php echo $design2; ?>/images/edit.png' alt='Edit' /></a></td>
<?php
}
?>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Then I changed to be like this:

```
public function test($cid, $cname, $cdescription, $cposition, blablablabla){

        $sql = 'SELECT c.id, c.name, c.description, c.position, (SELECT count(t.id) from topics AS t where t.kategori=c.id and t.id2=1) AS topics, (SELECT count(t2.id) from topics AS t2 where t2.kategori=c.id and t2.id2!=1) AS replies from categories AS c group by c.id order by c.position asc';
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $data = array('c.id' => $cid, 'c.name' => $cname, 'c.description'=> $cdescription, 'c.position' =>$cposition, blablablabla);
        $stmt->execute($data);

        $status = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        if($status){
            echo "MESSAGE";
            print_r($result);
        } else {
            echo $status;
            $this->error['alert'] = "Sorry, ERROR";
            Users::ErrorReport();
        }

    }
```

In part `blablablabla` is something unresolved.

Which makes me confused is, most do not use the example of the **AS** for the purpose of a section array. For example `name` or `description` while the code that I have used `c.name` `c.description` and others.

How do I make it work?

Comment: 'blablabala' this is not variable you are passing in the method .

Comment: @Drudge Yeah I know, but I mean `blablabla` section only for alias, so no need to focus on that part

Comment: Placeholders are either `?` or start with `:` Currently you have __NO__ placeholders in your query.

Comment: There are no placeholders in your query so no need to pass argument to your execute function.